# Is there any prime number of the form $0^1+1^2+2^3+3^4+4^5+....+(n-2)^{n-1}+(n-1)^n$?

Tags: prime-numbers

Let A(n)= $0^1+1^2+2^3+3^4$....+$(n-2)^{n-1}+(n-1)^n$. So:

- A($1$)= $0^1$
- A($2$)= $0^1+1^2$
- A($3$)= $0^1+1^2+2^3$
- A($4$)= $0^1+1^2+2^3+3^4$
- and so on....

Is there a prime number of such form?, because I checked quite plenty numbers of that form and I found that very few of them have least prime factor greater than $100$, and A($66$) is the first with $4$ digit least prime factor($1553$). My friend even told me that number of such form will never be a prime (!). Is there prime number of such form ?, what is the smallest prime number can be written as $0^1+1^2+2^3+3^4+4^5+....+(n-2)^{n-1}+(n-1)^n$ ?

Comment: Did you ask your friend why he said that?

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee, no but it seems he did some observations on it.

Comment: It seems that if n is even, then $2$ would be a factor since $2$ is a factor of the terms with even bases and two of the terms with odd bases when added together make an even number.  Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @FrankHubeny, A($66$) has least prime factor $1553$

Comment: @DieFarbemeinerHaus Yes, I think $n$ would have to be a multiple of $4$ for what I suggested to work in order to get distinct odd bases to sum together. Then the next term would be even, so these values should have $2$ as a factor for $n$ congruent to $0$ or $1$ and $n>1$.  That would only handle the easy cases.

Comment: $29, 105, 145, 217, 225, 281, 317, 325, 329, 389, 393, 401, 429, 461, 465, 473, 505, 517, 541, 589, 617, 649, 693, 717, 733, 757, 761, 793, 805, 829, 857, 897, 905, 913$ are all values of $n$ such that $A(n)$ has no prime factors lower than $10000$

Answer (score 10):

$A(6071)\,$ could be the first prime from your sequence but since this number has $\,22968\,$ digits the generation of a certificate proving its primality may take a very long time (some 'records' with Primo using ECPP are shown [here](http://www.ellipsa.eu/public/primo/top20.html#PrimoRecord) ).

The digits of $A(6071)$ are exposed for those wanting to confirm (or infirm) this conjecture :
(it is a [strong pseudoprime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_pseudoprime) and passed the pari/gp pseudoprime tests for $100$ random bases)

```
A(6071)=54773417
31803598421386181128381240549807419189188287669313278162155406498256198735879784
75831429475303742711226573721155625611606608472010269878858791213572417348157639
04571132968147831971624086053724606349786766214701964593189390053081663058354698
32491768754012642432945690454528177702124209588871747618762444120072518146738134
73016946526148544726686530003878058559422944409737513833122018940167729041614095
29501751948403585665999382635524979542034815873006899483216641972245573264979101
48943766507642664109671840657018281714544909948656436544759587154919527625810720
57761910405185528997434034206093833712804337889444955150596068303726239844345052
80505153783299937692881499648839237421592379216049734767951412889728026484643691
51134809022400999221151430606021081029599438552944016735846128691700588072465197
34803090539582220362577875310569827988291424042811136914743402415601357968648935
11281708873194497386216160435734756905953630733876626049833518487129288644964881
67807110515146543079264894503274618901039491221323462719572097651718256650159626
24711526112896347799505978239059971583566395037316185802352502981974630813880336
37511991956365853559125729767797702240711522349312186547107460165764059864471203
32209645716632923522669779045292656162243181377055022684033789506846065871484630
09332662242091763624620671068535283123630747802939635757973556422967879480397504
79115475866109155553798812262542916462602457559061174490852847461926531627285199
82519346255748354701691589381037301817579022044548927365256294192390956736761089
15684885853435986306059876195210096119479279322409402337227028596060169417155313
23978207505213811571260723762020303484022229771095654712819530445870738151592461
97538907243661943872544754368929491219306132811607401874606352594694796573644208
99255996905859118656277457182753437289325637075286165026657537036672420807174380
55265362488298668991426298326184447855515539631366341764900996528703322571269337
68685684485091913871405001234631751763103731267741065182847826184946700043701362
42142992491216899827718766511716073737556058413323176584153442597906851188203381
97471306498502393723917208904033403666751901329695154960478358186572835086544877
39033649463086150508661153285766188064151457139746181682485296472554250833799076
38610439869032285598304611459871891092083389607988324516528660824482454929462086
27224562201978434061239466318255577223906746262397731525520183148521276563172833
49976677112968260532792455343836492585457488675176523164469655810205933574687992
31765005547036116057825015661088424231432961972842128652745914307492176361122599
99833346042113594781992160078364132340659291932054696521288736454375441153879146
18394092214060762443948724416249260298916336310075561953884963789990649708803167
48752517452758499915401762088256866711203914626368905541767948928333906068479017
78737515943569391414953508338064722950870592229419501037708941621760939669203815
37697155864684532541553457087411467008148556534871362750919277094109062997285473
22134051232558032382926755134117259103057461942076758400050474594134407127230436
70248963473679517220073333340907073302835579436350886418700818321839878912717830
95394493730574853676743303855713639815832488187685386035010739922852377097986328
76486739885737957589352388242287485183529362179749936192373640910841726718122309
02310898585419964245322711971925640689962042523556764011249879243641591257262983
77704810466744913635218483164492931495898037105194347018060693511490546422791380
21175517100948818335581728181846749459714191289983310650668904645508803287105234
02405463723906343481874854219095742437272046246023216525193933026087555823459532
74119151050339134467769963985075410154895960677368983453300226935121690749320813
88279406292271023939993146862594918977555848544559446859403642951804864596893336
74472821367811706544938694779725041969812811741696458408989156804464242279469520
62433347119090102271388669018254318013294386137720360838576067248396892529383965
19141797537242458578897541142156489747596717879524568009389953676528292498427663
44771525906818769062878837553682204457064212573361609266481475089807572703596920
56764683652957329968687344197633947208319885829897738300754750828549888212640213
61509922375496544406048287012916772048177219571124503185810736413484683209809333
36604981489427955359534388599243779306409247268836924733771079729095275631991482
42810538821109460692459660789776634123680123778047758795701589988805351595803990
47727589853844397143260249643018425351166290965497386864705517158838137990901470
75306886008029269821865675645247472283811356276334342870061463635282550219063042
78952235884761841214104219829016502270791279150863453865570110224889120357737181
37244499940214122496099389385813162461937132993858619054894075190986855352417555
71480592638859296576354024401282776206248695353399092718875999610213662706793187
19587070790880648202097781240248883951842590395121690128225366842353838636769673
57360134789945822007168226739274075285326247596947164190833404066696787642358512
64148400716348377118916549162281532785074988785466475644545146276753521506232468
16053369166794723491229196317414631404656135308707505241926119250607355857035114
26551544824162305014556010704175166069547486643716361160683560470994022768885326
44855613616436946288952368258230332677511417902087085352483988087415410974646850
75135348025520999404333298146025460415147435992178364477854682179090461535555860
71615680305079832229019508965848511279533708699370098211539488960241666994708506
69275695365834209975667684872351039985754453478242294036047438214260597960713690
60117521096149495748075842413810619058387583658157363793466488437972024076991298
70308128808357245415447893580956884425222693245848068494827494132796233502466259
27403135028373905471044689752921136983895650700617326348216896904365795885942877
64658481076526226150277077575650490499050595698733944339430684685032250507099651
79324829497522146709541700562369153345514272049959998056296840425676639017979913
62115220143935725171740483641510579434060129542557288672227298121841023321729571
05286801781980183279482717774753479032913002369420268096417971272607020346600516
85516343344086099277028397871377580465866670997108347741937252099494081252538402
78792856704120064305195158256942001273689325140508016687479438933918812648226935
43013868779555497833241518183939358259796909104447088405391947120077173731576909
03980874197036463914774832406927502421183893359279055066013156489073105216215108
23639121355789347798958313108426152040231876475166275155065014031830124946082216
98649690816911279928004548739530320753770848002731455948623792375621759288993907
88600043837867852152449349482718780096143938000796503314919672408144895186537243
71598456190520699937841361144690958018684089562361513378771505009843715378983253
84470645315721951590566269332602333164084122550341971114277192730020111976037647
61271599036806993199551858403459024073369041685410379223689764275217706691051220
89375299412823544510890100471989080754810870498881124838272567347768618018141207
12520905762871546410899729913631257993496247974740807751355050636027324333192550
80858495226265875347211752531224741252730979093269468531761736374441064753276741
73195800202809017736167316234952952975107348143275352331622456176660344723714437
17921753146861510185441027546100220952039803453010738948447398103698147681832452
86958549235410356195051946883253558297095251091682652374003818970887398342082633
87407524805207919976952929761277269783498449443383751291197214536565066323794691
07426200276338835878926620265974590410349499127607248583256583610040101678041302
59027168037253449188956138711535644284880974024322054136407877149213356109882691
19945947922179650079137909411879530204280267031971739155712290674265998935548085
12207175987019549248423624284979520968017320012696668170194704300638471298781119
84373429857617137391895319305380433984286301275530839991296450878105637216199442
48537655414679981791937528309574550284816313946909464880400756627991790000577701
78145728071245522801665533156725993519520526717770518705609148540556748986289994
16574629194975345991418723741260083369497258065081673088266516185663741313027928
89970672483716927187739256710721765263122565172026788403303357333948813774395860
01835059136829395516450713959390760610598029212073070849826904064042349713540899
89836702194016115261007109738998946504599829834558813587675762558695204999178681
73012195023942524604874311785212503068833725948461304409703157746219198227973350
44406896514632688374593690574352242489230489967752738138851148043331638158102999
10780399676855101504255325228182777951485562992040920873758218205219165648666062
29387894995810156590737881528757924166518586358635096667208313998678221259648167
90408529468883993115738826314278123266912920001124826593345168287691671501517326
61167916254817786923377330863646895825454978839376553644214996647930206335854621
49293652405938098583277732677525576908775131153050557408147023585441037345068787
88694640453293599226822190671026644083836678703420561403403663856490634477105483
40700576844865638699106848915036033539115184941144296931131221544319217427441672
44974962340768850199386663809099644063010807347105506100786886947509146681164900
09811637754628331918720788673225420001409648368324549990247632185771716596974082
07481401388576054804362793314652981363096512781236061208532553927298136785869800
75848383331038996179572570356214360869337480084715365344182959790499801564711463
60922996878618746219968182661824276097561951764654144032664191339322233946992545
60369376315226502923070708849660847898210321815694252240449632288370770586863513
89907649141859853570002731900174123316205100946186344168668071934337033027027313
56850045869892358830242795623843304615408303726438858742159106731839311063212468
73475433608653814719726877874704175731674432912959439911120098802582378772173199
13721966725231452733815856210316305807944646560513187093502174155232635096297199
65594701591869118404267955599565483117474792685873374814609938135701935320581413
30701817600529232983090246728028756147601458482878784300814606516884265337936413
10154890442326303627981868602859527381741975633659232660578833547832853433249877
88386084469651860825824402865790814926044620947652962892287794923091596241185186
76553768171775129181886123297821494224832006976214606927370762579665698837743278
65608720568417728591823494354849123796320143049104286111524189778710210975927373
60694887938681313673101048138077245282884861407633354540674997094296811915742126
76430587734311153042501235295638878991782949806086285433913941739975312546075216
79717470042069462940839366623455811881712009522630664212058991935585469085081045
81003824522724781232303869435590606024792501341832604352751896008129657780066304
84618875164662209409537201536581556503236455229686203579307794920062374364865817
62431344168052716557361850942797860330418836828066561600277001859233325447754987
41066130934293071023369413098228479715543516184120136232470692252882636237382872
23586680627676657502634021016542205655048785061500086300333406655747530669360620
03567796263894312072785924073075282652156369998247975379910918777301182520120286
83722552159265055719100117783918448876916063965037632871845212083034425679672383
32507370820976441836850191435602676608705735715429217407890330511591179642809842
70628350515383015390265639169072911511634726708611203916576557800512704473339016
97000994452450120949014266131898724387952518457591909170883337651056072988960471
88084263543305641112944762885443916841332861140752821159239463250653582569152392
64018389447624804773843255789871009812036656131357577302082015471257872979453895
23077517922435825494965971759443898408228141547595686941074783467107235249079733
49447925100380441786078307673198115325907921092939551619426793398984349459267382
11706341000094507405599871772564091441819877431844497873756675935145255999621274
17125851505523372871660245422338162738260656095618971692444368943629073381728792
73788404663499580373195009118080599263622412062344436774302470377011787220462892
66695324008644574561015359236078048859662407690372133412973115791978486774542588
85889912397294441559363178310461355754699503836501747291342563792999534411707913
24701411079438971292907438207375244741077788342216329145583831008980527718947835
27644276196445929661911373074874048839816846791821465781522617122516590546898953
22509927817894046776135267256976906782476653834804904142118517391488882989289188
74582542038658612610143476159125400827123407824748780544894985786071881266297559
19275542069774631598291172166751780087803792973288061866382658826364369544641916
25846315174550742142750304216287360735575500977093620594350353020497183306793254
18432981723832973251029134502570155318033159937691012613641696946089784141390109
87944512727645502640650218164283027501397717948766520351441567395945355005936676
86586411241242060445523515954118349028145755355887668449097615821968003763978100
01684111085499148448999459059639752206185516835163576028283232480244516856500214
82624087949411667419704832236190269572683202548125134528707349587200835597786386
41058305001686496875810875976503957947693292892267408630496336711704232116748287
43064710576974970818617812486884375271571420092133687162506022812895642538324184
26032650345685783053984078843136959972417191074914747160520397034572775173923706
83546388767548450858355067316854419605460690878714470495741463818309725730464490
26163205205749416198661282371029576235890573165904248277682111840057872669865827
51049232143301898959250242029218648505222067123578401700334285107011268501965086
38719425739187474485191697479966080047339383301777340654887335964675564091001121
80840385335197780150640302598761228134212228517499400458847392777082284088301087
06629235671573763114216043522319611684135426717998264361386362536859543476886184
31888163235239633804208589575183314361384668062237256990352390569285756486796276
87180832734372635304317792575595055035991589051605241261616169738365847407006904
94161794444513695097932789461597198854950166358040711421252927605130982510302430
25916679683436967513781387592598123629677790993068092116400218606184638817634822
16681348304840404835854095582204788668321714678181622436491799421626612300165618
70495586113402884213763575329658750340155691573594237134634123192312560266908910
88936991938882664556439160411336594329133932223929253861355301428684521497961861
64744733408938049437773825040083208827479764812370555590523106423152360287633597
27020392964688401119612372756658909055673191520897217273958073347071897270895046
35945110414011420875138241472714708008681452931515519913636613735664477932798949
26546716226951430111113760089959736735215096992088284826025483481871867056218012
82735618243687611335656496907284923778268243462805028528579468225427310451487036
33226719872452792473197280769772386651274118740814222275202741822623951664669712
56461694162393748218968666964315972613126721863223222430305532507978507011090384
81864299594003941439794230264746987927188514391188145151028759459325388778488434
75406891345833590872561927189468755023930680473864477523778329905097041337654508
35199293383593278700410121338104552680492218516467584267687423582523077365718430
34118393445634011894720372843413310336981605801095994945149505641049534446568177
43503027949917190929994301648508872717659972288647236338028179868666785602913916
91550071061387028718278897489547515384393154712833331908733111700772564661514852
05292819119959609794280630477590768382560866321790866522677359574815769079530820
28247432784399060465271790153775083935572522164662279677513628579506641691911998
28738056729709622236087134422616030502838399571795649486440163205167980204245402
28040370867520833542742993218472813058252674205281476741012221478228430050261412
53299094883759246730884096487985270236659027151319973057580905041942286183753045
88741979177261875768723889613348110956652954118202622366900873070500677670408515
10015703349733567108781060183537156628560750084281270080329132833932046457338565
97102726411030385941276047885807192426354694159392107889793995021890061912370094
82193939057163195938072422804362359004434740330944093765347309082439222257455693
94455942317696715362443409550562163857267491433026746489475420534198010208897488
88631569520388603211505081408121660523303587286240447516143674043365208012301364
68964427820892655719494666342914647654655278334183135008695460818586302257169116
93439125875786863749460071432196813068720892879860071894037267421039853773272792
66363297919627406239631534544367048512736225567467815415121540675660973309504660
58393167220635908685884147283607533886464142622211556906127104114905050032380128
26997802055884053091969170131688974006956674576886081381459781715922113614934558
45690802615321987560754655562427604374116382285660835072560543732365966086792642
78403138846070074504413376342966076719957956884024500384237516628674082913094897
15700267612979178864929816321440744524096055180215375220455810936938712255540027
93301393048902781146614791040477813257563529401634532909840798834574591240303043
63677157686819095244414006185007701047443269286939714120849704974498650130729937
83755840230500546284292639987004783231669237937418666485408210922689029126940477
23773536757680791930961561752301169960841138920073182031335617289520558507211573
81465625653195632663530875519831350153039915322962621630685686702775048751197358
28075235608710630333518028189695708773199832661242338621034795239342301603589300
08584509429934178014513450730715377016357866535314042240920017712817870666970943
80240166046114182881721952715003969914812952977150796240173607368860362484988521
85725799816347846796463447590526678083880406422242889485494732748635889035231683
55600919401556305134143869129693367822465167782796366682669130036572186400487193
15495886909261784113339834091181935222356824448668810468802581280914051416761371
54319641251748349043827639295110178969345838244238044342541295049742153982523999
95668785648977244006548227759362572515297663760566378521209740778656380792254605
52164932895274737998479127521273399778511331134575646500371047152038248927686065
64703133515161306904696448662982890820125842051290297933144646757641947882979536
92088371250036413879523932214950788650804340499662199057105668865390242461696008
54980503334841706720076420169481516513577710092839882659744071292611431875155113
89232512302741135153459991675288744724527036083316241748178677242982647718383022
53100133534533586045758902103817093223846283441800077063496006688862785013884671
46815136898868304176634327097280488477191050049149656215900658325018405352358593
04055160381861647032723129876829279311926128142985722749642967000107914524860786
05267178845467586623339922383681280261475316912276870420479422865599576001631729
63993317678176623555322742211498945714802920592744243273799548488943037857770932
57483504734674053095566376843416919751028345836335303879779590234571004194372699
91885195122582857059158052634717187956834350563132252693245306606517706128314169
37805579942538818307006835147569297982073981934664013813710838944257202472048745
55741696741184245994526421299625403082699886789153143289266626456259446018801018
13686585181652785124733965590701931711167179081234378689647667575855384200662006
77445360736336939849666836989688205553449864100924011305187917584896855324945119
98110161545520772679329874429971067603820749890612277084008351941634175397508698
31548316304545778057009147978353185134447635089220601899123807325354743892183672
01394098737553090405388730603814362762490135412046127010057684396875911866553565
96256939441198720867236419261341273234658045824062187987636443278060788006835437
93329045123490286998461267731392021812034797678168116407200192443975639115228861
81198033754693526877893932752772762755632626356690563030552980816693836326654623
31203146524296239154015057326420781664081305991511274985730783336408797043712367
89637085277676174083203164448710857367140789014308790381140152804709659829394126
37725772479599717331284965251827886829834688574986168506513624520894394461844537
78596700108283408750079639417619727694621527224511829917908464809403185941940303
18827225047883065857009272667891393355112147011427079085075289249563874552919100
12536989621243335724519238493307490531380489638322015334228587727388159123975363
29474695722040058228784893391030585482179033398933890632132769980462027478072918
10468033538524534880952278282833746077068087353846198987766782177154906889383788
29558155271578018542293369582751310639691208680996586813848464789725001614979419
51610725759678859206145899992057330531350663426216678302632969230885291571739513
05528780464677950440079144943523364573544734032545659142428924075693368614978956
20987286595063334377126431247767612273712801752511098078688237765235681675150673
72362948222036866576890228555897877090756799950550457145937154602606193070987616
30218286096553418748661831679711234247294748420814313636326052907522233890075215
89315179606763550208124135269365226419281569366336685103195386196393875131145449
42491058633708691558755222273027265428355333246284504098295002221565550734344793
94168975856139751499813289055257215761993928810313449134999784581589606645175264
11040849546350599589727638194674410480371676406444490449080145930489097491496416
07667040386016873308401260958355824944380287839791868400048881457278515649594667
24258984743924593482736902002241709147763136861217953108262880056871189751156833
28494729979797061760763430541240881847439077697076146684544048775372214649301678
12731034138921824328612922755694797026961480263943262536993919928529047521320200
08819885957102854418251255194798198978763360504204547886894242020575245281962628
63873028352290749094711504868198018435466211979785281654596714820451942739372670
50721483970739875336810517819946351157495139070359776133720119438046520705493775
04512286206079053033182351474177298701357838558015551617287267902459482374451417
34412212595810230229479499307316936594444752399908911309806058023443743516988278
15646943247844426634046186090931478642160583571073132524576627623962950476221120
48569249713561207054082857655874219736383981327775049017194364637547707710816180
57806949864933336406956947429760412435005413368787315724633759971934527458147961
50723680788234816855035050337476650206704202429306908006280952459169465912122587
10398416968317207214905233745864820446648426909213082748095578794644109796690752
98738128127784237929465720059178915796792293311260846424938930601265293678121632
60672931887097915566379686868496588307587629871635582701827382066762452264908662
18790417348501552708576946980219537319544437815747084838240058495720097986030935
39714523661262299670507440913192824026486908900563842592993546981052162792197676
68907120276201023864421604207735978305071375112926157525568095548993492541795602
82408508520682582491409531340363883018570706815406254301730756117389009021208329
77382001117451469469748178082465177074742805607373988561098459977404942399392485
35862160006247286817243410976624601188857410343623555259630858821349435367074015
16076653981375490428641098727332177400928247612627218241990165375774539128336536
27784258015766264072769790985846999452395996891985511931002505492966659148324907
```

These digits were obtained in around $100$ ms using this [pari/gp](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/download.html) script :

```
s=0;for(n=1,6070,s+=n^(n+1));s
```

A primality proof using isprime(s) or variant should take *much* longer (if conclusive!)

Comment: Of the order of $460$ days extrapolating from smaller range with the formula ($N$ is the number of digits) : $$T_{\text{isprime}}(N)\approx\left(\dfrac N{230}\right)^{3.8}\quad\text{seconds}$$ using pari/gp $64$ bits on a $4$ GHz Xeon on only one core (I gave up after $3$ days). The certification should be much longer! The ispseudoprime(s) function on the other side took only some minutes.

Comment: I ran this in gp:  s=0;for(n=1,6070,s+=n^(n+1));factor(s) without finding any factors although I didn't expect to find any.  It took about 4 minutes on a Windows laptop.  This only checks factors less than 500,000 if I remember correctly.  So it might still be composite.

Comment: @Frank Hubeny: from the [online documentation](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/dochtml/html.stable/Arithmetic_functions.html) the functions factor(), nextprime, prevprime... replace the isprime requirement (for the number and its factors) by the much faster ispseudoprime (except if you set the 'factor_proven' default ; this is for the last version I think...). On the xeon the factor function took 2'9" while the ispseudoprime function took 2'8" so that the factor function probably didn't do much else ! :-). Thanks for the interest and the tests. Cheers,